# How to catch an event from a custom component(button) that is rendered into an ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to emit an event in Angular2 with clicking a button from a child component rendered inside a ng2-smart-table that is in the parent component as a column. Since there is no option to add an event listener in the tags of the child component that I render (I need to do it inside the tags )..
This way it's only rendered without options to give any attributes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To catch the value from custom componente

You have to declare in setting of smartable, into parent component

```
   setting.columns.button: {
            title: 'Actions',
            filter: false,
            type: 'custom',
            renderComponent: ActionButtonComponent,
            onComponentInitFunction(instance) {
              instance.save.subscribe(row => {
                console.log(this)
              });
            }
          }
```

---

and child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-button',
  template: `
 <span ngbDropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-raised mr-1" id="dropdownRaised4" ngbDropdownToggle>Actions</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownRaised4">
      <button class="dropdown-item ontop" (click)="onClick(event)">
        <i class="icon-x"></i>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./action-button.component.scss']
})
export class ActionButtonComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
  renderValue: string;
  @Input() value: string | number;
  @Input() rowData: any;

  @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
  }

  onClick(row) {
    this.save.emit(row);
  }


}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hey can you tell me please how can I initialze the component with data from parent component?